# How to use the upper-case sum from mtpro2 with newtxmath?

Tags: greek, newtxmath, mtpro2, newtxtext

The `\sum` provided by `newtxmath` is nice, but it just doesn't look as clean as the one from `mtpro2`, or perhaps the default computer modern font. Is there a way that I can import that symbol so that I can use it along with the others provided by `newtxmath`? Using `mtpro2` in Overleaf just doesn't work, and I don't really want to have to install the package locally just to get one symbol.

I tried following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513021/how-to-import-few-symbols-like-int-and-sum-from-mtpro2) post to no avail.

The left image uses `newtxmath`'s `\sum`, whereas the right does not. Of course, the $n=1$ would, ideally, use the `newtxtext` font with only the sigma being altered.

[image: Good sum][image: Bad sum]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187313/213708) post seems to give me what I want.

```
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}
```