# How to use Computer Modern lambda with newtxmath package?

Tags: math-fonts, newtxmath, computer-modern

I'm trying to use the CMU `\lambda` in my document because I prefer its appearance over the one from `newtxmath`. I had a similar sentiment about `\sum`, but I was able to find a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187313/213708) that replaces the sum symbol. I tried looking into the font tables but couldn't make heads or tails over them, even after consulting the documentation. I'm just not sure what is the code for lambda; it seems "50 is \sum. Below is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,theorem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdsymbols}     {OMS}{mdput}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mdlargesymbols}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{mdsymbols}{"66}{mdlargesymbols}{"08}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{mdsymbols}{"67}{mdlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}{\mathord}{mdlargesymbols}{"7A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}{\mathord}{mdlargesymbols}{"7B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}{\mathord}{mdlargesymbols}{"7C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}{\mathord}{mdlargesymbols}{"7D}

\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}

% \let\lambda\relax
% \DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{???}

\makeatletter
\def\downbracefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd$}
\def\upbracefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatother

\let\textbraceleft\relax \let\textbraceright\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbraceleft}{%
  {\fontfamily{mdput}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"66}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textbraceright}{%
  {\fontfamily{mdput}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"67}}



\begin{document}
\fonttable{cmr12}
\Huge
\[
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: surely you want the whole Greek alphabet not just a single character?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I like how the CMU lambda looks but prefer most other symbols from newtxmath.

Comment: a font is an artistic creation of a designer trying to provide a coherent view of information. Unless you are producing ransom notes designed to be shocking, choosing different fonts for each letter is unusual. It's like saying you like the Mona Lisa,  but want to over-paint a different smile

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The intent was to mimic something akin to Math time pro, where it has a roman Times font for text and math, but a \sum like the one from CMU. Since mtpro2 is effectively antiquated and doesn’t work in Overleaf (not to mention expensive), I figured this was the next best thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{cmletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{cmletters}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{cmletters}{"15}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! How did you know to use cmletters and “15?

Comment: @TheProgrammer You can search in `source2e.pdf` or `fontmath.ltx`.